# status/notification bar is appearing despite Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Tags: android, notifications, android-manifest, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

In my AndroidManifest.xml I'm using the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` attribute in the application tag. When I start my app from the apps menu, it works: both, the title bar and the status bar are hidden and the app uses the full screen.

However, when I start my app on boot (it is the default home screen), the app still uses the full screen but the status bar is visible.

It looks like that my app is running in the back ground. Starting a new activity in the same app doesn't change that behaviour. I need to restart the app in order to hide the status bar.

Any solutions?

using Android 2.3.6

Comment: Have you tried the programatic method of requesting no titlebar?

Comment: yes, i tried that, too. the titlebar is not the problem. my application is in fullscreen, but the status bar is showing on top layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! I had overridden following method:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
    System.out.println("Onactivity attached :");
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Seems like setting the window type to `TYPE_KEYGUARD` in the first activity causes troubles. I put the code into another activity, now it works, the status bar is never shown :)